# htaccess internal server error rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have a pretty simple .htaccess file that is causing a 500 Internal Server Error but I don't know why. I am using WAMP with virtual host wdc.test, my root folder is C:\wdc, and my www folder is C:\wdc\www, links that look like this href="wdc.test/title" come up with the error when I know that it should be pulling up the index file in www

my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/index.php [L,QSA]
```

thanks

Comment: Your `DocumentRoot` might be `C:\wdc\www` instead.

Comment: where is your virtual host pointing to?

Comment: you're exactly right, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  points to C:/wdc/www instead of c:/wdc, I changed /www/index.php to index.php and it works, if you post the answer I'll mark it

Comment: the file httpd-vhosts.conf file points to c:/wdc/www, thanks to you too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely due to the reason that your `DocumentRoot` points to `C:\wdc\www` instead.

If that is indeed the case use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```